# Right outer join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: `Users` and `Files`.

Users table has 10 rows, Files table has 450 rows which has a column for user ID's (`UserID`).

I want to query list of all People and files they last downloaded. Files table has `LastDownloadTime` field which is of type `DateTime`.

This is my SQL query;

```
Select
    Users.Name , Files.Name
FROM Users
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Files on Users.ID = (
    Select Files.UserID
    FROM Files
    ORDER BY LastDownloadTime DESC Limit 1
)
```

Above query returns all Users and Files. What should be the right query for this?

Comment: Did you try?

Select Users.Name , Files.Name FROM Users RIGHT OUTER JOIN Files on Users.ID = Users.UserID ORDER BY Files.LastDownloadTime DESC Limit 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Select
    u.Name,
    (Select f.Name from Files f where u.ID = f.ID order by LastDownloadDate LIMIT 1)
FROM Users u
```

Comment: @Frank thanks, missed that. Is 'LIMIT 1' the way it's done in MySQL?

Comment: It is, but MySQL had/has problems using LIMIT in a subquery. I'm not sure about the current status of this problem in the different MySQL versions.

Comment: perfect results give me this code. I include other tables too. Now Just I want ask a question. How Can we write this sql code using Join ?

Comment: @atromgame do you really need to use a join? It won't help you out in any way. This is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

See these:

```
 SELECT Users.Name , Files.Name 
    FROM Users 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    ( SELECT Files.Name 
      FROM Files 
      INNER JOIN
          ( SELECT TOP 1 Files.UserID ,Max(LastDownloadTime ) as LastDownloadTime 
                    FROM Files 
                    ORDER BY LastDownloadTime DESC,Files.UserID  ) as f2
  ON Files.UserID  = f2.UserID  AND Files.LastDownloadTime  = f2.LastDownloadTime 
   ) as f  ON Users.ID = f.UserID
```

Comment: I have tried and this query show now Just one user and all files :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the RIGHT JOIN? Your question seems different.

```
Select 
    Users.Name 
    ,f2.Name 
FROM 
    Users  
        JOIN (SELECT userid, MAX(lastdownloadtime) AS latest FROM Files GROUP BY userid) f1 ON f1.userid = Users.id
        JOIN Files f2 ON (Users.ID = f2.userid AND f2.lastdownloadtime = f1.latest);
```